# mean and least error on the line

Tags: clustering, variance, mean, k-means, arithmetic

Suppose I have a line on which i have points in non-decreasing order. My intuition tells me that if I want to minimize the squared mean error on some subset of 3 (or other number) points, I would like to take 3 subsequent points, or rather check all 3-subsets of subsequent numbers on the line to find one with lowest square mean error. 
Suppose I have 4 points, and subset of points a, b, d, with c point in between points b and d. All points are in increasing order: **a__b__c___d**.

Now, I have square mean error for a, b, and d: **f(a, b, d) = (a-m)^2 + (b-m)^2 + (d-m)^2**, where m is arithmetic mean of the subset. My intuition tells me, that if I now choose subset a, b, and c, then **f(a, b, c) < f(a, b, d)**.

HOW can I prove THIS? I tried to do it myself using geometry and using a lot of arithmetic but it is still elusive. Cannot also formulate the question on google to look for answer.

Comment: Have you tried Konig-Huygens? Is m the mean of a, b, c *and* d, or only of three?

Comment: Hi, only three. Also the proof should be extended to arbitrary number of points.

Comment: Definitely try König-Huygens. It should make the proof easy.

Comment: But this theorem states that E[X^2]-EX^2 = Variance. Im quite unsure if it fits in here because there is no probability involved in my example, but if i consider mean as expectation of points with equal probability....mmm..that might work...THanks for suggestion

Comment: Try expressing f(a,b,c) in terms of variance. then f(a,b,c)-f(a,b,d) and remove common terms. Maybe factor to get (c-d).

Answer (score 1):

A "mean square error" is a multiple of a variance; the multiplier depends only on the count of data.  Thus it appears you want to prove this lemma:

> When $x_n \lt x_{n+1}$ are the two largest values in a dataset of $n+1$ values $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n, x_{n+1}),$ the variance of $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_{n-1}, x_{n+1})$ exceeds the variance of $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n).$

[*The variance is proportional to the sum of squares of all possible differences of the data.*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18200/919) (Again, the constant of proportionality depends only on the count $n.$) When you replace $x_n$ by $x_{n+1},$ you increase all the differences between the highest value and the other $n-1$ values, eaving the count the same and without changing any of the other differences.  Therefore the variance increases, *QED.*

---

#### Comments

Because there are always many ways to demonstrate algebraic relations like these, there are other solutions to this one.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/361801/919 shows another way: apply it to remove $x_n$ and then to adjoin $x_{n+1}$ to the dataset.

A purely algebraic demonstration of the key assertion -- the variance can be expressed as a sum of squared differences -- appears at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/225758/919.

If you prefer a Calculus approach, you can also define a function $f(x)$ to be the variance of the dataset $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_{n-1},x)$ for all $x$ exceeding the largest of the $x_i.$  This is a quadratic function of $x,$ so compute the derivative $f^\prime(x)$ and show it is always positive.